# C# Tutorial - Inheritence and Defining a Type?

Tags: inheritance, c#-4.0, derived-types

I am working my way though this tutorial [dotnetacademy exercise 5.1](https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2045/Pages/11)
I have tried many different ways to solve this, and when I try to verify, it won't work.  I tried this:

```
public class Atom
{
    public Atom()
    {

    }

    public Atom(int protons, int electrons)
    {
        Protons = protons;

        Electrons = electrons;
    }

    public int Protons { get; set; }

    public int Electrons { get; set; }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    var Hydrogen = new Atom(1,2);
    }
}
```

and I get an error saying "You must define a type named Hydrogen.", but I thought that was what var Hydrogen did.

I tried this too:

```
public class Atom
{

    public Atom(int protons, int electrons)
    {
        Protons = protons;

        Electrons = electrons;
    }

    public int Protons { get; set; }

    public int Electrons { get; set; }

}

public class Hydrogen : Atom
{
    public Hydrogen() : base("Atom") {}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

and this one won't compile.  There is an error at the line "public Hydrogen() : base("Atom")" which says "There is no argument given the corresponds to the formal parameter 'protons' of 'Atom.Atom(int,int)'"

I've even asked a C# developer, who can't figure out why my attempts aren't working.  Can anyone help?  I was just getting the hang of these concepts and now I'm stuck.

### Thanks!

Edit:
Just to give full context of that link, they start the embedded validator with this code:

```
public class Atom
{
    public int Protons { get; set; }

    public int Electrons { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

    }
}
```

and the instructions are this:

> 1. Create a constructor on the base type Atom that accepts an integer named protons and an integer electrons. The constructor should
>      set the values to the associated properties Protons and Electrons.
> 2. Implement a derived type Hydrogen that inherits from Atom and provides the correct arguments for protons and electrons to the base
>      constructor.

I haven't resorted to posting in a forum for help, because I have been researching my way through and trying to figure this out, but I am wondering if they are just being strict in "how" they want it solved, regardless of if you can solve it many different ways.  I just want to see how they want us to solve it! lol

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> There is no argument given the corresponds to the formal parameter 'protons' of 'Atom.Atom(int,int)

This is the constructor of the base class:

```
public Atom(int protons, int electrons)
```

But in the derived class you're trying to use this:

```
base("Atom")
```

That is, you're supplying a `string` value instead of two `int` values.  Provide the `int` values instead:

```
public class Hydrogen : Atom
{
    public Hydrogen() : base(1, 1) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quick. Now I get "You must call the base class, passing in the correct number of protons and electrons."

Comment: I added this to the public program under main : var stupid = new Atom(1,2);  and I still get that error.

Comment: @missscripty: I guess whatever validator you're using is checking the actual values too.  My mistake, Hydrogen has 1 proton and 1 electron.  I've updated my example accordingly.

Comment: I'm using the validator right in the link I put in the post.  It verifies it right there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  Thanks for help David! Here is the final code:

```
public class Atom
{

    public Atom(int protons, int electrons)
    {
        Protons = protons;
        Electrons = electrons;
    }

    public int Protons { get; set; }

    public int Electrons { get; set; }
}


public class Hydrogen : Atom
{
    public Hydrogen() : base(1, 1) {}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    var Nucleus = new Hydrogen();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```
public class Atom
{
    public int Protons { get; set; }

    public int Electrons { get; set; }

    public Atom(int protons, int electrons)
    {
        Protons = protons;
        Electrons = electrons;
    }
}

public class Hydrogen : Atom
{
    public Hydrogen() : base(1, 1)
    {
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple mistake, property = variable runs and variable = property results in compilation error

```
public Atom(int protons, int electrons)
{

protons = Protons;
electrons = Electrons;
    
}
```

**VERSUS**

```
public Atom(int protons, int electrons)
{
Protons = protons;
Electrons = electrons;
    
}
```